# mongodb refer to an attribute of a document in query

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a MongoDB *collection*, where I have *documents* with the following structure

```
{
   ...
   distanceDeviation: 2.0,

   loc: [
      [24.77, 67.5],
      [24.78, 67.6],
      [24.79, 67.7],
      [24.80, 67.8],
      ...
   ]
   ...
}
```

I have this *collection* geo-indexed (using *ensureIndex* on `loc`).

I want to have a query where if I send it two points Mongo returns me *documents* from the *collection*, which have both the points in their `loc` array.

I have been able to do it using `$within` with a fixed `$radius` parameter as follows:

```
{
    "$and": [
                {
                    "loc": {
                        "$within": {
                            "$center": [
                                [
                                    24.812640000000002,
                                    67.01985
                                ],
                                1.5
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "loc": {
                        "$within": {
                            "$center": [
                                [
                                    24.900070000000003,
                                    67.16828000000001
                                ],
                                1.5
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
}
```

HOWEVER, if instead of `1.5` specified as radius I want to specify that the attribute **distanceDeviation** is used which is a part of this *document*.

Is there anyway to achieve this preferably without `$where`. If NOT then, how can I do it with `$where`.

Comment: no, there is no way to pass a variable to find() that's based on a field in the document.  I don't recommend using $where for performance reason among many others - if you expand on what exactly this data represents, maybe there is a different way to structure the data (if you have that option) to get what you want with regular query?

Comment: There is a possibility to restructure the document. The loc variable in this document simply represents a route, and distanceDeviation represents how much flexibility is allowed for this route. I am supposed to check if another startPoint, endPoint lies within this route or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility, though a little awkward, to do the job with `aggregate()` and its `$geoNear` operator. Awkward, because aggregate allows only one `$geoNear`, that has to be at the top of the aggregation pipleline. So, we'd have to do two aggregates and then merge the result.

The idea: `$geoNear` will return the distance of a given point from each of the points in the "loc" route. We can then take the minimal distance, test with the `$cond` operator, whether it is within the `distanceDeviation` and return the documents, where this is the case.

The result is an array of documents that match for the first point. Then repeat the operation for the other point and then merge the two arrays to a list of documents that appear in both arrays.

This is how it works (for better readability, I used other coordinates)

```
db.xx.drop();
db.xx.insert( { distanceDeviation: 2.0, loc: [ [0,0], [10,-10], [20,10], [30,0] ] } );
db.xx.insert( { distanceDeviation: 0.1, loc: [ [0,0], [10,-10], [20,10], [30,0] ] } );
db.xx.ensureIndex({ loc: "2d" });
db.xx.find();

// points to query:
pointA = [1,1]
pointB = [21,11]

aggA = db.xx.aggregate([
    { $geoNear: { near: pointA, distanceField: "dist" } },
    { $group: { _id: { oid: "$_id", dev: "$distanceDeviation" }, min: { $min: "$dist" } } },
    { $project: { oid: "$_id.oid", isNear: { $cond: [ { $lt: [ "$min", "$_id.dev" ] }, 1, 0 ] }, _id: 0 } },
    { $match: { isNear: 1 } },
]);


aggB = db.xx.aggregate([
    { $geoNear: { near: pointB, distanceField: "dist" } },
    { $group: { _id: { oid: "$_id", dev: "$distanceDeviation" }, min: { $min: "$dist" } } },
    { $project: { oid: "$_id.oid", isNear: { $cond: [ { $lt: [ "$min", "$_id.dev" ] }, 1, 0 ] }, _id: 0 } },
    { $match: { isNear: 1 } },
]);

print("\nObjects with point near route:\n");
aggA.result.forEach( function( a ) {
    aggB.result.forEach( function( b ) {
        if ( a.oid.toString == b.oid.toString ) { print( a.oid ) };        
    });
    // Note: this can be optimised        
});
```

The result is:

```
> db.xx.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5161da88ab49f42c329f4228"), "distanceDeviation" : 2, "loc" : [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 10, -10 ], [ 20, 10 ], [ 30, 0 ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5161da88ab49f42c329f4229"), "distanceDeviation" : 0.1, "loc" : [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 10, -10 ], [ 20, 10 ], [ 30, 0 ] ] }

>> // run the aggregates

Objects with point near route:

ObjectId("5161da88ab49f42c329f4228")
```

Another, completely different approach would be to **"draw" a closed polygon around the route** at distance "distanceDeviation" and store this also in the document. This would allow to search for `$within: $polygon` (similar to your search within a circle) and would return a match also for points that are close to the route but not necessarily close to one of its constituent points.

Please, refer to the [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) for more information on [aggregate()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/), [$geoNear](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#stage._S_geoNear) and [$polygon](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/polygon/)